# Trigger a hover effect while hovering on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mousehover

At the moment, I am learning how to write in javascript and jquery.I wrote a simple jquery code where when you hover one div, a second div will be hovered too. However, the code I wrote is not working. My knowledge is not enough to fix the mistake I made by myself that's why if someone can help me I am going to be really grateful.

PS: I know that it can be done only with CSS but I am not interested in that.

My code:

```js
$('.Box1').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('.Box2').trigger(e.type);
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:green;
}

.Box1{
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  height:10vh;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.Box1:hover{
  background-color:#FFF;
}

.Box2{
  position:absolute;
  top:10vh;
  width:100vw;
  height:20vw;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Box1"></div>
<div class="Box2"></div>
```

Comment: You can't trigger CSS `:hover` selector with JavaScript.

Comment: And regarding your posted code, what triggering `.Box2` mouseover event are you expecting to do??? There is no event nor `:hover` css set, so?!

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to "fake" a hover event. Take any code that you would have attached to the .Box2:hover css and assign it to a class. When you hover over .Box1, add the class to .Box2, when you hover off, remove the class. The code would look like the following:

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/rasexe/edit?html,css,js,output)**

## CSS

```
.Box2{
  position:absolute;
  top:10vh;
  width:100vw;
  height:20vw;
  background-color:red;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.Box2:hover, .Box2.hovered {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$(function () {
  $('.Box1').mouseover(function(e) {
    $('.Box2').addClass("hovered");
  });
  $(".Box1").mouseout(function () {
    $(".Box2").removeClass("hovered");
  });

  // or optionally using .hover() for in/out handling as per A. Wolff's comment
  $(".Box1").hover(function () {
    $(".Box2").addClass("hovered");
  }, function () {
    $(".Box2").removeClass("hovered");
  });
});
```

Comment: As a side note, you could use `hover()` in/out handler:   http://jsfiddle.net/xwv6a4ub/

Answer (score 0):

Your code does trigger the mouseover event for Box2 - you can test this by adding a handler:

```
$('.Box2').mouseover(function() {console.log('hello')})
```

However, this does not activate the css :hover property of Box2 (if it were defined). You will probably need to write a handler for Box2's mouseover event that manipulates the css properties.